# Raspberry Pi Tomcat Switch amd LED on page

Tags: java, tomcat, raspberry-pi

I new to tomcat and Java, looking for example of a switch and LED on webpage.

I have hardware that has a button and Led. push button and when done LED goes off or flashes if errors.

I would like to trigger remote and see LED.

I found this http://iqjar.com/jar/controlling-the-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins-from-a-web-browser/
and its a start... how do I read the input from hardware LED  and show on page.

Comment: Can you provide an schematic of your hardware? However, the link you mentioned seems ok, what parts are giving you trouble? Final comment, have a look at http://nodered.org/, it not java, but in my opinion is more appropriate for what you are looking to do.

Comment: The Switch one side ground the other to hardware and gpio port with pullup resistor... ( so will need some mods for 3v ) the LED one side to 5v  with resistor and other to hardware and gpio port

Answer (score 1):

The [webiopi framework](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/) will allow you to control the GPIO pins from your browser. webiopi is an [Internet of Things (IOT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things) platform targeting the Raspberry PI.

You can control the GPIO pins via the browser

[image: GPIO Control]
By clicking on a pin to set the status.

There is a tutorial [here](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/INSTALL) and some more discussion [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15257) and [here](http://trouch.com/2012/08/21/webiopi-control-your-pis-gpio-with-a-browser/) and even a [video](https://youtu.be/BrCXJNJ5x_g)

Comment: The simplest solution may be to use an of the shelf library and then modify it to remove the parts you don't need